# Ansible Md5 checksum

Tags: ansible, yaml, md5, checksum, cisco

**I have been trying to Install the new OS when the Md5 result matches but I am unable to get pass that. I keep getting error: "The error was: error while evaluating conditional (md5_result.stdout[0] == ""asdh3jk23h4343243434334". 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\ Please suggest **

```
>  - block:
>           - name: verify MD5
>             ios_command:
>               provider: "{{ creds }}"             
>               commands: sh file bootflash:{{ki}} md5sum
>             register: md5_result
>           - name: Install OS 
>             check_mode: no
>             nxos_install_os:
>               provider: "{{ creds }}"
>               kickstart_image_file: "{{ki}}"
>               system_image_file: "{{si}}"
>               issu: desired
>             when: md5_result.stdout[0] == "asdh3jk23h4343243434334"
```

The output of var: md5_result

```
  "md5_result": {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false,
    "stdout": [
        "asdh3jk23h43434343434343"
    ],
    "stdout_lines": [
        [
            "asdh3jk23h43434343434343"
        ]
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: What is the output of `- debug: var=md5_result` when inserted right before that `- name: Install OS` task?

Comment: "md5_result": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "stdout": [
            "asdh3jk23h43434343434343"
        ],
        "stdout_lines": [
            [
                "asdh3jk23h43434343434343"
            ]
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Then please update your question to include the real error message, because that output and your claimed message don't square up; You also should include the output of `ansible --version` since it's further impossible to track down if you're using ansible 0.55 beta or something equally silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work:

```
    - block:
      - name: verify MD5
        ios_command:
          provider: "{{ creds }}"
          commands: show file bootflash:{{bin}} md5sum
        register: md5_result
      - debug:
          var: md5_result.stdout[0]
   - block:
      - name: Install OS
        nxos_install_os:
          provider: "{{ creds }}"
          system_image_file: "{{bin}}"
          issu: no
          timeout: 500
        when: md5_result.stdout[0] == "asdh3jk23h43434343434343"
```